# Converting branched multiline into series of single lines in shapely

Tags: python, shapely

If I have a multiline string representing a branched network with a common starting point (red network in pic below):

[image]

Does anyone know how to convert this to a set of individual single linestrings in shapely? With each individual linestring starting at the common starting point and ending at each specific end point? Assuming I have a shapely multiline object as a starting point.